# Unknown number of constraints in scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to solve a constrained minimization problem:

[image]

where y_max, a_i are known numbers. I keep a_i's in a numpy array and y_max as a number. The function g is also explicitly defined, but I cannot understand from the documentation how to define the constraints.

I have tried to write

```
bnds = Bounds[[0, 1] for k in range(len(rates)),
                       [rate[k-1], rate[k+1]] for k in range(1,len(rates)-1),
                       [self.ymax, self.ymax])
```

where `rates` is my initial guess for values of `eta_i`. It throws an

```
error:
  Input In [21]
    [rate[k-1], rate[k+1]] for k in range(1,len(rates)-1),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

How do I feed the constraints and the bounds I need to scipy.optimize?

Comment: did you try parenthesizing the generator expression? that means writing `(` `)` around the `blah blah for blah blah in blah blah`?

Comment: @user253751, I have, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. I'll try again, but the question about the other constraints still stands.

Comment: scipy wouldn't tell you how to define the constraints because it's a python thing and not a scipy thing. you know you don't have to write them directly in the function call, right? you can create them any way you want

Comment: `[i+3 for i in range(3)]` is a `list comprehension`.  `(i+3 for i in range(3))` is a generator expression.  Without either [] or  () produces a syntax error.  This is basic Python.  Until you understand Python and `minimize` better, it may be a good idea to write out the bounds explicitly (for small `n`).  Start small and work your way up to the full problem.  It also helps  you write clearer questions.

Comment: Post a minimum complete example. Invalid syntax on its own is not enough for us to see what you're actually trying to do.